# Why is the last line of list cut?

Tags: blackberry, datagrid, java-me

I'm working on a blackberry app with intended target OS5+.

I'm creating a GridFieldManager to display data that is fetched from a web-service. Second column of data is often multiline, so i set the lines to be of a bigger height than standard. This is the code for my GridFieldManager:

```
//Creation and property settings

GridFieldManager myGrid = new GridFieldManager(myScreenData.getSpese().size(), 3, GridFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH|GridFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
        myGrid.setColumnProperty(0,GridFieldManager.AUTO_SIZE, Display.getWidth()/3);
        myGrid.setColumnProperty(1,GridFieldManager.AUTO_SIZE, Display.getWidth()/3);  

        myGrid.setColumnProperty(2,GridFieldManager.AUTO_SIZE, Display.getWidth()/3);
        myGrid.setRowPadding(3);
        myGrid.setMargin(3,0,3,0);
        for(int i=1;i<myScreenData.getSpese().size()-1;i++){
            myGrid.setRowProperty(i, GridFieldManager.FIXED_SIZE, getFont().getHeight()*3);
        }

//title population
        myGrid.insert(new LabelField("DATA"), 0,FIELD_LEFT);
        myGrid.insert(new LabelField("CAUSALE"), 1,FIELD_LEFT);
        myGrid.insert(new LabelField("IMPORTO"), 2,FIELD_LEFT);
//Data population       
        for (int i=0;i<myScreenData.getSpese().size()-1;i++){
            System.out.println("aggiungo "+i+" di "+(myScreenData.getSpese().size()-1));
            SpesaDateAsString mySpesa = (SpesaDateAsString)myScreenData.getSpese().elementAt(i);
            myGrid.insert(new LabelField(mySpesa.getData(),LabelField.FIELD_LEFT|LabelField.FOCUSABLE),0+((i+1)*3),FIELD_LEFT);
            myGrid.insert(new LabelField(mySpesa.getCausale(),LabelField.FIELD_LEFT|LabelField.FIELD_VCENTER),1+((i+1)*3),FIELD_LEFT);
            myGrid.insert(new LabelField(mySpesa.getImporto(),LabelField.FIELD_LEFT),2+((i+1)*3),FIELD_LEFT);


        }
        System.out.println("aggiungo la tabella");
        result.add(myGrid);
```

The problem here is that **last line of list gets cut**. Here's the screenshot:

[image: blackberry storm simulator screenshot]

Does anyone know what to do? Why is this happening?

I have tried every possible combination of parameters for the row properties (FIXED,AUTO,PREFERRED... ETC) and every possible combinations of paddings and margins. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: where is the screenshot?

Comment: edited, somehow image link does not get displayed so i re-added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
for (int i=0;i<myScreenData.getSpese().size()-1;i++){
```

Why your limit is `myScreenData.getSpese().size()-1` and test is strict `<` ?
Either you use less or equal operator or your limit should be `myScreenData.getSpese().size()`

Comment: i will try it out right now. You might be on the right track. (se è questo mi sparo!)

Comment: Good luck! (Se è questo prima di spararti accettami la risposta! :D)

Comment: Nice! (grazie mille, da giorni ci scombattevo!)

Comment: Beware that you wrote it two times in your code! Check thoroughly!